# R Shiny Radiobuttons several lists

Tags: shiny, radio-button

How can I display more than one list in R shiny to get input as Radiobuttons?

I already can show one list as

```
    radioButtons("testname", "Glucose", choices=c( "AA", "BB", "CC"))
```

but cant has more than one list to choose one option from all the lists at then end.

And I would prefer to have lists horizontally next to each other.

At the end I would like to have something like this:

Biomarkers list

Glucose       o AA         o BB         o CC

Lipid
o A
o B
o C

Comment: Do you mean you want to select only one options form the list?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to have them as several lists but just be able to choose one option out of everything.